# Error Country after enabling state and country picklist

Tags: apex, api, translation-workbench, country-and-state

Since I have enabled  state and country picklist I get the following error:

Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0013O00000rrYAFQA2; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, There's a problem with this country, even though it may appear correct. Please select a country/territory from the list of valid countries.: Shipping Country: [ShippingCountry]Class.

I am trying to update an account trough the api:

```
{
    "Firstname": "John", 
    "Lastname": "Cool", 
    "Street": "Custom Street", 
    "Housenumber": 1, 
    "HousenumberAddition": "A", 
    "Postalcode": "0000AA", 
    "Newsletter": true, 
    "City": "city", 
    "Country": "Nederland",
    "Language": "nl-NL" 
}
```

In my State and Country/Territory Picklists I have the following active:

```
Country/Territory Name  :Netherlands
Country/Territory Code  :NL
Integration Value   :Netherlands
```

Is there a way I can make the translation Nederland acceptable. I already tried the translation workbench but the did not resolve this

Comment: Sounds like you know the issue here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000335972&type=1 Translation does not apply to picklist _values_ - use the right country name and it'll work.

Comment: There's an ugly solution involving a proxy field `CountryX` on Account that accepts alternate country spellings. Then  a before save flow or before trigger coerces the alternate spelling in `CountryX` to the defined integration value for the `Country` field

Comment: Did you build a custom REST API for this?  Those don't look like standard account field names.  If you've already imported your translations according to [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000318511&type=1), then you may need to open a case with Salesforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we resolved this by updating the data corresponding to the country mapped